# Erro com função serialize() + PHP

Tags: php, jquery

estou usando a função serialize pra enviar dados de um formulário para uma página PHP:

index.php

```
<form id="formfeira" method="post">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="horario">Horário de funcionamento:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="horario" name="horario" placeholder="das 8h às 18h">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pagamento">Formas de pagamento:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pagamento" name="pagamento" placeholder="à vista ou nos cartões Visa e Mastercard">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="quem">Quem somos:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="quem" name="quem" rows="3" placeholder="descreva aqui..."></textarea>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="salvaFeira()">Enviar dados</button>
    </form>
```

funcoes.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
function salvaFeira(){
  alert($("#formfeira").serialize()); //aqui funciona
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "salvarFeira.php",
    data: $("#formfeira").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data); //não chega aqui
    }
  });
}
```

salvarFeira.php

```
<?php

include 'conexao.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "feira");
$res = $mysqli->query("insert into feira (horario, formapagamento, quemsomos) values ('123', '456', '789')");

echo 'teste'; 
?>
```

Desisti de tentar resgatar os dados e estou apenas fazendo um insert comum e retornando a palavra teste

Porém, não está salvando no banco de dados. Caso eu execute diretamente o arquivo salvarFeira.php, o mesmo salva os dados no banco corretamente.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador (F12, geralmente), na aba Network você consegue ver todas as requisições feitas na página. Veja se a requisição POST está sendo feita e, se sim, selecione-a com o *mouse* e veja a resposta obtida.

Comment: ótimo, consegui descobrir. erro 404, faltou incluir a pasta onde o arquivo se encontra. valeu mesmo, eu estava a tarde toda quebrando cabeça com isso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss fiz o teste agora e salvou no banco de boa. porem a linha alert(data) do arquivo js ainda não está sendo executada.

Comment: Conferiu se a resposta foi 200? Já tive problemas co a configuração do servidor PHP que não entendia que o arquivo havia executado com sucesso e precisava definir o código manualmente com o `http_response_code()`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss resposta foi 200 sim

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss olhei melhor a tela Network e aparece assim: em Params aparecem os dados do formulario. Em response aparece o código html da página index

Comment: Da Index? Tem algum .htaccess no projeto que possa estar redirecionando a requisição?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não sei, estou usando wamp, como faço pra saber?

Comment: Veja se existe o arquivo .htaccess no diretório do projeto. Não lembro se ele fica visível por padrão no Windows, mas no Linux é um arquivo oculto.

Comment: não tem, no diretório do projeto só tem os arquivos do bootstrap, index, js e o php

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acrescentei ao jquery o código `error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(status, error);//Captura o erro e envia ao console }` e o mesmo está retornando 'error', mas não especifica qual é o erro. como faço pra que ele diga qual erro está ocorrendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copiei seu código e testei, o que está errado é que definiu o **type** do elemento **button** como **submit**, para efetuar uma requisição ajax, na realidade a propriedade deveria estar setada como **BUTTON** como abaixo:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="salvaFeira()">Enviar 
dados</button>
```

Enquanto estava como submit não funcionava porque a página recarregava e perdia a requisição enviada por ajax.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu teste agora funciona perfeito, e para você ?

PS: Não se esqueça que o jquery deve estar incluso na sua página para isso funcionar:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Abraços...